How to store an ability mechanic?
I'm working on a project which is a collectable card game, where cards gonna have very different abilities, for example as in Hearthstone - one card kills another card, another gives mana, another deals damage, another gives additonal damage, another doubles it's damage, so those are completely different abilites. But I don't know where and how to store these abilites. How is it made? I think it's not possible to store this information in the DB. Or is it?

Why do you want to store them in a database? How often do you want to introduce new cards? How unique is the effect of an effect?

You may be interested in How to create data driven effects/abilities for collectable card game, How to implement trading card game's "special effects cards"?, How should I implement card effects in a card game?, Attaching scripts that trigger on specific events, and Q&A in the [tag:effect-modifier] tag. (Search results)

If not in a DB, then where should I store them(that is a part of the question)? Each card is gonna have a unique effect, sometimes maybe they are gonna be the same but with different values (different amount of damage f.e.). I don't really know how often I gonna introduce new cards, but at the beggining it's gonna be 20 cards.

What game engine are you using? If you are unfamiliar with even the basics of storing data, perhaps you should consider some introductory programming books or courses, so you have a better foundation of knowledge to work from.

Does it matter which engine I am using (it's UE5, anyways)? Why is it basics? I think that I should somehow store code as a string in the DB, but I don't know if it's a best practice to do so or there are some other ways

If I gonna store this information in a JSON file for example, how do I establish connection between card information stored in the database and information stored in the JSON file? And which information about the cards should be stored in the JSON files and which in the DB? For example for health, cost, rarity, damage, spells?
